# Which local homeos to numerical space are bijective?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I am reading T. Szamuely's book on Galois groups and fundamental groups.
As preparation to the algebraic case, he recalls the topological case.
So I am wondering if a surjective local homeomorphism $f$ from some connected space $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is necessarily a covering, in which case it would be bijective since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is simply connected.

What about the differentiable case?

Comment: Local on the source or on the target?

Comment: "numerical space" -> "Euclidean space"

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think Euclidean space has less structure than R^n, so I'd be more inclined to call the latter "Cartesian space"...